# theoritical question regarding existence of a certain set in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory

i have a theoretical question: if a set of phrases $\sum$ has the following property foreach $a,b \in \sum$ $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$.  can we build an infinite set $\sum$  so that it follows the above properties, but that for each $a \in \sum$ exists $b \in \sum$ so that $a \not \Rightarrow b$?

wondering about that, can such a thing exist?

thank you very much

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the problem correctly. You can take propositional letters $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots$ and consider $\Sigma= \{p_0, p_0\wedge p_1, p_0\wedge p_1\wedge p_2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: so that for each $a \in sum$ exists $b \in sum$ so $a \not \rightarrow b$

Comment: Its almost always better to use `\Sigma` to get $\Sigma$ rather than `\sum` to get $\sum$ in any situation where you aren't talking about iterated addition.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you use different names for the two different sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all r in R, let p(r) be r <= x
and $\Sigma$ = { p(r) : r in R }.

If r <= s then p(s) implies p(r),
If s <= r then p(r) implies p(s),
Thus (p(s) implies p(r)) or (p(r) implies p(s)).

However, p(r+1) does not follow from p(r).

If you want a denumerable collection, use Z instead of R.

Comment: can i please ask you an additional theoretical question? if $\sigma$ has the following properties: foreach $a,b \in \sum$ $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$, and each phrase in $\Sigma$ has a model in it, then essentially $\Sigma$ has a model?